# Swipe Images using ViewPager programmatically not by finger

Tags: android, image, android-viewpager, swipe

I am using a ViewPager class to swipe images in an activity.I can do it by finger.I have disabled finger feature but i have two buttons below images i.e Next and Previous.I want to swipe images by those buttons and i have no idea how to do it please help.My question is similar to question number 9650265.Thank You

Comment: then it's not called `ViewPager`. It's `ViewFlipper`

Comment: No . i am using viewpager

Answer (score 1):

Try out 
[ViewPager.setCurrentItem](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setCurrentItem(int, boolean))

Comment: thanks buddy but i have already tried it..it didn't worked @p

Comment: @AshishPrajapat: Since this would appear to be the right answer, please explain what "it didn't worked" means.

Comment: Nothing happened ? Did you execute it on the main thread and after setting the adapter ?

Comment: forcewill,after setting the adapter

Comment: @CommonWare please check my [code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/is5gepjryyz06wv/Test.zip?dl=0) and pardon me for my mistakes..i am just a beginner in android willing to learn new techs.Thank you

Comment: [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tn0460z9ip8lxap/Test%202.zip?dl=0) is a working version, as expected setCurrentItem works 
I just moved your buttons to the MainActivity layout, since there is no need to have them created for each Page in your viewpager unless you want them to animate also if so please move them back to the adapter